# How do I prove an arbitrary polynomial does not have constructible solutions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I know that the field of constructible numbers is composed of integers and square roots of integers under addition, multiplication, and square roots. How do I tell if a certain polynomial has constructible roots?

Comment: What you "know" is wrong.  For example, the square root of any positive constructible number is constructible.

Comment: Sorry, edited. I mistyped

Comment: A real number is constructable , if and only if it is algebraic and the minimal polynomial has a degree which is a power of two ($1$ is also allowed). Therefore the famous problems "square the circle" and "double the cube" are not solvable because neither $\pi$ as a transcendental number nor $2^{1/3}$ as a number with minimal polynomial of dgeree $3$ are constructable.

Comment: In other words, the polynomial must split into irreducible factors with a degree that is a power of $2$ (or $1$). In the case that the coefficients are rational, this condition is also sufficient.

Comment: @peter: No. You have elements of degree 4 which are non constructible, as for example a root of  $X^4-X−1$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.. The condition of the degree is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: @GreginGre You are right, so my first comment is not correct either. At least , it is a necessary condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @peter said, $\alpha$ must be algebraic of degree of power of $2$, but this condition is not sufficient (You have infinitely many counterexamples).

In fact, you have the following theorem.

**Thm.** Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ be a complex number. Then the following conditions are equivalent:

1. $\alpha$ is constructible
2. There is a tower of fields $E_0=\mathbb{Q}\subset E_1\subset\cdots\subset E_{r-1} \subset E_r$ such that $\alpha\in E_r$ and $[E_i:E_{i-1}]=2$ for all $1\leq i\leq r. $  (this is why you have the necessary condition on algebraicity and the degree)
3. $\alpha$ is contained in a **Galois** extension whose degree is a power of $2$
4. $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and he splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has degree a power of $2$, or equivalently
5. $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and the Galois group of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is a $2$-group.

Note that conditions 3,4,5 are the most useful.

For example, if $\alpha$ is a root of $P=X^4-X-1$, then $P$ is irreducible, and its cubic resolvent is also irreducible. Then the splitting field of $P$ contains a subextension of degree $3$, and by 4), $\alpha$ is not constructible.

You should find all these reuslts and the missing definitions in any good book on Galois theory.